# Zoom to group layer using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, extents, group-layer

I have a group layer that I have populated with a collection of feature layers. When I right-click on the group layer and select "Zoom to Layer" the view zooms so that I can see the full extents of all of the feature layers. I'd like to be able to do this using ArcPy, but so far I haven't been able to determine the proper method. The group layer doesn't have its own Extents, so I can't set the Extent of the current data frame using `groupLayer.getExtent()`. Is there a simple way to replicate what the right-click menu does?

There may also be a case where I want to zoom to only the visible layers inside of the group, so a method that allows me to do that would be even better (seeing as my first case is a special case of this one with all layers set to visible).

The code below shows how I am currently trying to go about this. Essentially I am looping through some collection of datasets that have already been brought into my mxd file to export pictures. The `groupLyrDict` and `zoomLyrDict` dictionaries contain the layer objects for the group layers that I am using. They are created elsewhere in the code and work correctly, so for instance `zoomLyrDict[tuple([dataset,"Groupview"])]` returns a group layer that contains several feature layers.

```
datasetNames = ["ds1", "ds2", "ds3"]
for dataset in datasetNames:
    groupLyrDict[tuple([dataset, "Groupview"])].visible = True
    df.extent = zoomLyrDict[tuple([dataset,"Groupview"])].getExtent() # causes an error because the group layer does not have an Extent object
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, outDir + "\\my_view.tif", "PAGE_LAYOUT", resolution = 300, tiff_compression = "NONE")
    groupLyrDict[tuple([dataset, "Groupview"])].visible = False
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the MinX of all layers in the group, repeating for MinY, MaxX and MaxY, and building an extent object?  For help with code please always include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Well it seems this question may partially be a result of approaching a problem from one direction for so long that I end up missing some other obvious ways. I think what you're suggesting would work, but I was also hoping there'd be a simpler way that didn't force me to loop through all the layers in my file (it sure would be nice if arcpy had some sort of ListLayersInGroup functionality).